# Get the response if site didn't crawl due to robots.txt

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to crawl user defined websites but not able to crawl the site where robots.txt is preventing the crawling. That's fine but I want to get the response where I can show to user that "the site you have entered doesn't allow to crawl due to robots.txt".

There are other 3 types of prevention for which I got the code and handling accordingly but only this exception (i.e. prevention by robots.txt) which I cannot handle. So, please let me know if there is any way to handle the case and show the appropriate error message.

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Scrapy 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [**ROBOTSTXT_OBEY**](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey)

```
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False
```

More information about [**RobotsTxtMiddleware**](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt):

> This middleware filters out requests forbidden by the robots.txt
>   exclusion standard.
>
> To make sure Scrapy respects robots.txt make sure the middleware is
>   enabled and the ROBOTSTXT_OBEY setting is enabled.
>
> If Request.meta has dont_obey_robotstxt key set to True the request
>   will be ignored by this middleware even if ROBOTSTXT_OBEY is enabled.

Comment: Technically this solution is correct, however not sure about legally